# Excel macro to concatenate strings in a column

Tags: excel

For the first unique name in Column A create a string in column C comprised of the strings in column B separated by the tilde "~" character. The cells in Column C under the first set of strings should be blank. The sheet shows the first two species with how the strings should look, write a simple macro to create the remaining. Here is a zipped sheet you can download with the data in it:

http://ibird.com/hub/Elance_Job.xls.zip

Here is how the sheet looks in case you can't download it:

```
Col A           Col B              
Clark's Grebe   Clarke's Grebe_040514_LE_01  
Clark's Grebe   Clarke's Grebe_040514_LE_02
Clark's Grebe   Clarke's Grebe_040514_LE_03
Clark's Grebe   Clarke's Grebe_040514_LE_04                                     

Col C (what I need to create)
Clarke's Grebe_040514_LE_01~Clarke's~Grebe_040514_LE_02~Clarke's Grebe_040514_LE_03~Clarke's Grebe_040514_LE_04

Col A           Col B
Common Loon Common Loon_040514_LE_01
Common Loon Common Loon_040514_LE_02
Common Loon Common Loon_040514_LE_03
Common Loon Common Loon_040514_LE_04
Common Loon Common Loon_040514_LE_05
Common Loon Common Loon_040514_LE_06
Common Loon Common Loon_040514_LE_07

Col C (what I need to create)
Common Loon_040514_LE_01~Common Loon_040514_LE_02~Common Loon_040514_LE_03~Common Loon_040514_LE_04~Common Loon_040514_LE_05~Common Loon_040514_LE_06~Common Loon_040514_LE_07
```

Comment: Will the list be sorted by birdname then by filename?

Answer (score 0):

I need an extra column:

in D2 put the following formula, and copy it down

```
=IF(A2=A3,B2&"~"&E3,B2)
```

in C2 put the following formula and copy it down

```
=IF(A2<>A1,D2,"")
```

**EDIT**
Sorry ... just noticed you were actually looking for a macro.

If you didn't want to use an additional column, you could use the formula from D2, and then conditionally format it for White on White when the current row A cell matches the previous row A cell.